# How to turn off flutter camera plugin shutter sound?

Tags: ios, flutter, plugins

I'm using flutter camera plugin for taking pictures. But I couldn't turn off the shutter sound. I tried

```
_camera = CameraController(
  cameras[0],
  ResolutionPreset.high,
  imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.yuv420,
  enableAudio: false
);
```

But I think enableAudio is for videos. How can I turn off the shutter sound?

Comment: I believe that the shutter sound happens as default on iOS. Try setting the phone to "silent mode" and see if it still happens.

Comment: @RaphaelSauer Yes of course in silent mode there is no shutter sound. But the point is turn off this sound programatically.

Comment: @bdre got any solution for the above issue ??? If you got the answer, Please help.

Comment: @Akki Hi, yes I got. When capturing photo with front camera, there's no ability to disable shutter audio cause privacy reasons. So I use video. I'm recording a video for a second and I'm getting first frame of this video to avoid shutter sound of photo capture.

Comment: @bdre isn't that's weird as we have already asked for the permission from the user for the front camera

Comment: @Akki I think it's a precaution to avoid some scenarios like take photos secretly.